# How to change date format to Month (abbreviated text)

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

how do i change formate date from 25-Feb-2013 to Feb only?
Means here, it only extract the abbreviated month only.
i try to use this code but it does't work and it turn Feb to Jul

```
            Sheet1.Range("A2:A9") = Format(Date, "mmm")
```

Comment: record a macro of you changing it to the format you want using the cell format.  I always try that when i get stumped on stuff like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sheet1.Range("A2:A9") = Application.text(Date, "mmm")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
Sheet1.Range("A2:A9").NumberFormatLocal = "mmm"
```

As suggested by @user3271518, this is found by recording a macro, changing the format and then looking at the macro recorded.